# SSRS if string says this then change it to this

Tags: visual-studio, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have a field in SSRS and it returns from SQL saying "Incomplete"

In SSRS I want to say anytime this field says "Incomplete" to change the string to "Pending"

This has to be done in SSRS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use an expression:

```
=iif(Fields!Field1.Value="Incomplete", "Pending", Fields!Field1.Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, you can do something like:

```
=Replace(Fields!thisItem.Value, "Incomplete","Pending")
```

Comment: Um, no.  It is syntactically exactly what works.  Anytime the word "Incomplete" appears in the field, it will be changed to "Pending".

Comment: sorry, my bad. Comment retracted.

Comment: Actually, you are right in suggesting that there is a better way to implement it.  My code will change every single instance of the word "Incomplete".  Decker97's code will first check to see if "Incomplete" is the only word in the field and then update.  It really depends on what the OP is looking for.